# more efficient sampling algorithm

Tags: sampling

I am currently sampling clusters of data as follows: 1) Sample a variable $X$ from distribution $F$, 2) If $X>B$, $B$ being a fixed constant, then add $X$ to the cluster with probability $p$, if $X\le B$, then add $X$ to the cluster with probability $q$, 3) Repeat until the cluster reaches a fixed size, say 20. This takes a pretty long time and I am wondering if there is a quicker way to directly sample the 20 variables to obtain a cluster that looks the same as my current scheme. I know how to sample directly from the conditional distributions $X\mid X>B$, $X\mid X\le B$, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If the probability to be in one cluster is $p$ and the other is $q$, which I assume equals $1-p$, you can first draw a Binomial variate
$$N\sim\mathcal B(20,p)$$and then draw $N$ variates from the conditional $F(x|X>B)$ and $20-N$ from the conditional $F(x|X<B)$. The resulting sample will be distributed from$$pF(x|X>B)+qF(x|X<B)$$which is equal to $F$ only if
$$p=\mathbb P(X>B)$$
This in turn means that this is equivalent to simulating from $F$ and cluster later.

If the size of only one cluster is fixed (the question is unclear), 20 say, simulating a Negative Binomial variate
$$M\sim\mathcal N\mathcal B(20,p)$$and then draw $20$ variates from the conditional $F(x|X>B)$ and $M$ from the conditional $F(x|X<B)$ is the equivalent solution.

If the sizes of both clusters are fixed (the question is unclear), simulating separately from the respective cluster distributions is obviously faster.

If the simulation is intended to produce an iid sample of size $n=20$, the distribution of said sample is proportional to
$$pF(x)\mathbb I_{x>B}(x)+qF(x)\mathbb I_{x<B}(x)$$
that is
$$\dfrac{pF(x)\mathbb I_{x>B}(x)+qF(x)\mathbb I_{x<B}(x)}{pF((B,\infty)+qF((-\infty,B))}
=p^\prime F(x|X>B)+(1-p^\prime)F(x|X<B)$$
where
$$p^\prime = \dfrac{pF((B,\infty))}{pF((B,\infty)+qF((-\infty,B))}
$$
and which reweights differently the two components of $F$ corresponding to the half-lines $(-\infty,B)$  and $(B,\infty)$. The result is still a mixture and hence the number of values from the first component can be first drawn as a Binomial variate
$$N\sim\mathcal B(20,p^\prime)$$and then draw $N$ variates from the conditional $F(x|X>B)$ and $20-N$ from the conditional $F(x|X<B)$.

Comment: There is only one cluster, and $p$ and $q$ are not related. I don't think the question is unclear, perhaps you can suggest improvements? When I wrote "sampling clusters" I meant sampling iid clusters, each of size 20.

Comment: I do not understand the concept of a single cluster.